# Warnings in passing three.js scenes into backbone.js models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, three.js

I am running into errors when trying to pass an instance of THREE.Scene into a Backbone.Model like so:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
new (Backbone.Model)(scene);
```

And end up with the warnings:

```
DEPRECATED: Object3D's .eulerOrder has been moved to Object3D's .rotation.order. three.min.js:148
DEPRECATED: Object3D's .useQuaternion has been removed. The library now uses quaternions by default. three.min.js:148
```

I am currently using three.js r59 and backbone.js 1.0.0

Comment: For a starter, may be you shouldn't use minified js file during your development. Also, it is just a deprecation warning using console.warning not an error https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L58

Comment: I am aware of what it is doing; I am interested in why it is doing this.  In my code I am doing this quite often, and it is creating quite a bit of overhead for me in console messages.  I have looked at the non-minified source of threejs but couldn't figure out why it was calling the blocks these warnings were found in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in how backbone creates its models.

To create a model it reads in all properties of the object( This causes the warning) and sets them to the named property on the model.